# calling sum() on a list of numbers extrcted from a document

Tags: python

I need a little help with a sum function. I'm trying to locate all the lines with prefix "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" in a document. After i extract them i want to call sum() on them and calculate the average. Thanks, heaps!!!

```
for line in (fhand):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    else:
        n = float(line[line.find(":") + 1:])
        a = sum(n)
        count = count + 1
    print (n)
    print (a)

print (total / count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood this correctly, but as far as I can see, you only need to store the sum of the values in a variable, something like:

```
total = 0.0
count = 0
for line in (fhand):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    else:
        n = float(line[line.find(":") + 1:])
        total += n
        count = count + 1

print (total / count)
```